# Huge performance discrepancies at each run, with the same CNN architecture

Tags: classification, cnn

I have set up a CNN architecture with 3 Convolutional layers with pooling (except the last one), a fully connected layer and a logistic regression layer. All the layers, except the last one, have a ReLU activation function to train on the MNIST dataset. I have followed [LeNet tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html)

When I train my model, I have some weird behaviours. One time out of five (approximately), my network will early-stop at the second epoch with an error of 89% (so, quite bad) and sometimes, the same network will yield a test performance of ~1.3%, which is great in my opinion. This is totally random and this is weird.

I thought of two reasons on why this might happen :

- **Weight initializations might not be right**. However, I have double-checked the weights initialization for each layer type. While the LogReg layer initializes its weights at 0, the two other layers (FullyConnected & ConvPool) initialize theirs weights according to a normal distribution whose parameters are

  np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = np.sqrt(1.0 / fan_out),size = filter_shape)
- **There is an error in the SGD step**. I double-checked my SGD step with the tutorial's, and I can't spot any discrepancies. Moreover, I don't understand why it would work sometimes, and be broken at others.

Is there any other reasons I might have not considered?

Comment: First you need to make absolutely sure your implementation is correct

Comment: CNNs benefits from larger layer depth, have you considered adding more layers? Also, have you tried controlling the seeding of your numpy random seed? [numpy random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do)